# How to transform an object into a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-2.7, yaml

I have a return of an object `<generator object load_all at 0x000000000309AB40>` from a function that opens and reads a YAML file. From this return, I need to create an organized file dictionary.

```
#FILE YAML TEST.yaml   
---
MAIN:
  Name: Jaqueline
  Age: 30
  City: New York
OTHER:
  State: True

______________________________________________________
#PYTHON
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
from pathlib import Path


def file_yaml():
   yaml = YAML()
   stream = Path('TEST.yaml')
   yaml_conf=yaml.load_all(stream)
   print(yaml_conf)

   return yaml_conf


yaml=file_yaml()
dictionary=?????
```

yaml is an object `<generator object load_all at 0x000000000309AB40>`

If I make:
    ...

```
yaml=file_yaml()
dictionary =dict(yaml)
print dictionary
```

I have: `{'MAIN': 'OTHER'}`. I lost a lot of information from the archive !!!
How can I create a correct dictionary with the data of the file?

Comment: you need to open your `yaml` file first before you pass it in to `load`

Answer (score 3):

It works fine for me:

```
import yaml

with open('random.yaml', 'r') as fin:
    yml = yaml.safe_load(fin)

yml


{'MAIN': {'Name': 'Jaqueline', 'Age': 30, 'City': 'New York'},
 'OTHER': {'State': True}}
```

Comment: I would like to keep the function that returns me an object. How to do it?

Comment: sorry I do not understand the question

Comment: @user199858 are you asking to keep the generator object?

Comment: And other thing, I don't have `safe_load` in ruamel.yaml. This package is newer than  `yaml `, right?

Comment: sure it is newer I have never heard of it and from my experience I have only used `pyyaml`